# how can i group data per day and per hour on Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have to collect data for a graphic that shows visits, and for example if i want to show a day in the graph i have to divide the visits per hour.
my object is like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab1119b646e371568c8cf9e"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-20T13:46:30.018Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

i tried this code

```
db.getCollection('monitors').aggregate([{
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "year": {"$year": "$date"},
                "dayOfYear": {"$dayOfYear": "$date"},
                "interval": {"$subtract": [{"$minute": "$date"}, {"$mod": [{"$minute": "$date"}, 60]}]}
            }, "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }
    }]))
```

and it works but it collects only datas per day. i need to collect also per hour. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you didn't use `$hour` in the `$group` stage. You will need two groups one for day and another one for hour.

Something like

```
db.monitors.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{"$year":"$date"},
      "dayOfYear":{"$dayOfYear":"$date"},
      "hour":{"$hour":"$date"}
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":"$_id.year",
      "dayOfYear":"$_id.dayOfYear"
    },
    "dailyCount":{"$sum":"$count"},
    "hourlyData":{"$push":{"hour":"$_id.hour","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: just to ask, how can i collect them by a specific day?

Comment: It is by year-day and within each day it is by hour. Can you add the expected output to the post ? Do you need the actual data along with count ?

Comment: i have to extract data for a graph. for example, if i want to show for a specific day how many visits i had divided by hour, i need to have results of the specific day i need and divided per hour

Comment: Do you mind creating a new question please with expected output and all other details ?